# Can you create a app file in a relative file path using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-slides

I can see how to create a .txt or blob file in a file path from the root using DriveApp, but I can't figure out how to create a file in a relative file path.

Details:

I have a Sheets file in

```
My Drive/Folder 1/Sheets File
```

This file uses Apps Script to create a Slides presentation. That presentation is generated in My Drive, so I end up with the main app in `My Drive/Folder 1` and the file it creates in

```
My Drive/Slides File
```

Instead, I would like to find the folder ID of the relative folder that the sheet is stored in and generate the presentations in there, so that it ends up that the presentations are in

```
My Drive/Folder 1/Presentations Folder/Slides File
```

In order to create or access the folder `Presentations Folder` I need to know the path `My Drive/Folder 1/`, but this is a script that needs to be copy and pasted to a bunch of different people's Drives and the paths where they save the Sheets file will all be different.

Is this possible to do, or do I just have to create the presentation in the root?

Comment: Possible. Provide [mre]

Comment: I'm using this code to create the file:

`const pres = SlidesApp.create(title);`

This creates the Slides presentation in the root. I do not know how to make it create in the subfolder that the file that's calling this line of code is currently in.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: @AmberButler In addition to last "Note" of @Tanaike 's answer, To get the id, use `const folderId = DriveApp.getFolderById(ss.getId())`, where `ss` is your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const path = "My Drive/Folder 1/Presentations Folder"; // This is from your question.

  // Retrieve folder using the path.
  let folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder(); // This is a root folder.
  path.split("/").slice(1).forEach(folderName => {
    const folders = folder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : folder.createFolder(folderName);
  });

  // Create a file.
  const title = "sample title"; // Please set your expected title of the file.
  const pres = SlidesApp.create(title);

  // Move the created file to the specific folder.
  DriveApp.getFileById(pres.getId()).moveTo(folder);
}
```

- In this sample, it supposes that `My Drive` of `const path = "My Drive/Folder 1/Presentations Folder";` is the root folder.
- When this script is run, the file of `const pres = SlidesApp.create(title);` is created to the folder of `Presentations Folder` of `"My Drive/Folder 1/Presentations Folder"`. When the folder name is not existing, the folder is created. When the folder name is existing, the existing folder is used.
- If you want to use Drive API for creating the file, please modify the above script as follows. In that case, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services.

  - From

    ```js
    // Create a file.
    const title = "sample title"; // Please set your expected title of the file.
    const pres = SlidesApp.create(title);

    // Move the created file to the specific folder.
    DriveApp.getFileById(pres.getId()).moveTo(folder);
    ```
  - To

    ```js
    // Create a file.
    const title = "sample title"; // Please set your expected title of the file.
    Drive.Files.insert({ title, mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES, parents: [{ id: folder.getId() }] }, null, { supportsAllDrives: true });
    ```

#### Note:

- As a simple way, if you have already known the folder ID of "Presentations Folder", you can use the following script.

  ```js
  DriveApp.getFileById(SlidesApp.create(title).getId()).moveTo(DriveApp.getFolderById("folderID"));
  ```

  But, from your question, I thought that you might want to use the path. So, I proposed the above sample script.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename)